# Select all thead and tr has td except the last column

Tags: javascript, jquery

i make this code to get all the value of the table and to insert in array with index name.

codes work well, but i want to exclude the last column of the table.

```
                var array = [];
                var headers = [];
                $('#idTable th').each(function(index, item) 
                {
                    headers[index] = $(item).html();
                });

                $('#idTable tr').has('td').each(function() 
                {
                    var arrayItem = {};
                    $('td', $(this)).each(function(index, item) 
                    {
                        arrayItem[headers[index]] = $(item).html();
                    });
                    array.push(arrayItem);
                });
```

i already tried `not(:last-child)` but the last column still included.

check my jsfiddle. 
https://jsfiddle.net/del17/1yx3csrw/3/

Comment: can you add sample snippet including html and script

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/del17/1yx3csrw/3/ here is my working code with html

Comment: added solution. @del

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```js
var array = [];
var headers = [];
$('#idTable th:not(:last-child)').each(function() {
  headers.push($(this).text())
})

$('#idTable tbody tr').each(function() {
    var arrayItem = {};
    $(this).find('td:not(:last-child)').each(function(i) {
      arrayItem[headers[i]] = $(this).text();
    })
    array.push(arrayItem);
});


console.log(array)
console.log(headers)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="idTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>C</th>
      <th>D</th>
     </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>a1</td>
      <td>b1</td>
      <td>c1</td>
      <td>d1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a2</td>
      <td>b2</td>
      <td>c2</td>
      <td>d2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I think for what you want to do it's better to use "text" instead of "html".

Also, don't use index too much if you know you iterate through the same order.

It's better to use "push" if you want to add elements to an array like you seem to do here.

Comment: this is one of way to do. Upvoting this answer.

Comment: It's better to put it as "answered" ;)

Comment: Yes. better way to do. @djcaesar9114

Answer (score 1):

here is  fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/p0qu5mc9/

```
var array = [];
                    var headers = [];
                    var columnlength = document.getElementById('idTable').rows[0].cells.length; 
                    $('#idTable th').each(function(index, item) 
                    {

                        if(columnlength-1 > index){
                        headers[index] = $(item).html();
                        }

                    });

                    $('#idTable tr').has('td').each(function() 
                    {
                        var arrayItem = {};
                        $('td', $(this)).each(function(index, item) 
                        {   
                            if(columnlength-1 > index){
                            arrayItem[headers[index]] = $(item).html();
                            }
                        });
                        array.push(arrayItem);
                    });

                    alert(JSON.stringify(array));
```